# Wrong Resizing in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to resize an Image Frame to size 256,256 instead it is resizing to 32,256.The original frame size is 402,638. I want the image to be of size 256,256 to feed into my neural network.

Can you suggest some solutions or possible causes?

Here's my Code

```
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('soccer.mp4')
i=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    size_x,size_y,size_z=frame.shape
    frame=frame.copy()
    frame=cv2.resize(frame,(256,256),interpolation =cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    frames=[]
    frames.append(frame)
    frame_res=model2.predict(frames)
    frame=frame_res[0]
    
    if ret == False:
        break
    cv2.imwrite('out/'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
    i+=1
```

I'm Encountering the following Error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9ce0f742ec18> in <module>
      7     frames=[]
      8     frames.append(frame)
----> 9     frame_res=model2.predict(frames)
     10     frame=frame_res[0]
     11 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1627           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1628             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1629             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
   1630             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1631               context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    860       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    861       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    863       if self._created_variables:
    864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2939     with self._lock:
   2940       (graph_function,
-> 2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3356               call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):
   3357             return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(
-> 3358                 args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3278 
   3279     graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
-> 3280         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   3281     self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function
   3282 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3204             arg_names=arg_names,
   3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3207         self._function_attributes,
   3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\Users\sourabh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:274 assert_input_compatibility
        ', found shape=' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(32, 256, 3)
```

Comment: I had the same error, so I solved it using ```np.reshape()``` method after ```cv2.resize```. So one of the possible solutions is to use ```np.reshape(frame, (1, 256, 256, 3))```

Answer (score 0):

Why not expand the dimensions as such it seems much more simpler than creating an array and appending it

```py
frame_copy = frame.copy()
frame_copy = cv2.resize(frame_copy,(256,256),interpolation =cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
res = model2.predict(np.expand_dims(frames, axis=0))
```